# How to pass multiple values to a single grep -v option

Tags: shell, grep

I have a text file, named my_data.txt, with the following contents:

```
#  define var1 and var2
var1=101
var2=202
// display var1 and var2
echo ${var1}
echo ${var2}
```

I want search all occurrences of var1 but not those in a line starts with '#' or '//'. I can do this:

```
grep var1 my_data.txt | grep -v '^#' | grep -v '^//'
```

output:

```
var1=101
echo ${var1}
```

The results is correct. The question: is there any way to pass both values '^#' and '^//' to a single -v option?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
grep -v -e '^#' -e '^//' file | grep 'var1'
```

Or with an extended regular expression (`-E`):

```
grep -v -E '^(#|//)' file | grep 'var1'
```

Output:

```
var1=101
echo ${var1}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can make use of grep -P you can use a Perl-compatible regular expression and a single grep command.

```
grep -P "^(?!#|//).*\bvar1\b" my_data.txt
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!#|//)` Negative lookahead, assert not `#` or `//`
- `.*\bvar1\b` Match the word var1 in the line

Or using `awk` skipping the line that starts with # or // and print a line that contains var1

```
awk '/^(#|\/\/)/{next};index($0, "var1")' my_data.txt
```

The examples will output:

```
var1=101
echo ${var1}
```